# Are there tools that trace from a database table to java classes?

Tags: java, dependency-analysis

There are many tools that trace dependency between java classes like Lattix, 
But, Are there tools that trace from a database table to java classes ?(Ideally, create CRUD table automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I think Hibernate does that for you. Have a look [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables)

Answer (score 0):

You should turn the log at the TRACE level on hibernate classes and set show sql property  what is actually Hibernate doing. This apply to every persistence framework you use.